# $S$ is the set of Integers, $a,b$ both belongs to $S$, $a\sim b$ if both $a>b$ and $b>a$.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

The original question was

> "Is the relation $\sim$ is a equivalence relation?"

I can mathematically figure it out that this is not.

Since $a$ is not related to $a$, as $a$ satisfies neither of the conditions.
Basically no two pair of integers satisfies this.

My question is,

> 1. Is my approach correct?
> 2. Since no element is mapped to no other element, can we even call it a relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not an equivalence relation since, as you have correctly determined, it is not *reflexive*.

It is the binary relation $\emptyset$ since $a\not{\sim}b$ for all $a, b\in \Bbb Z$, because $\emptyset\in \mathcal P(\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z)$.